# Where store context attributes using several servers (J2EE)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-deployment

I'm currently developing a Wepapp using Java EE with Tomcat Server. I'm using context attributes like:

```
ServletContext context = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
String defaultUser = (String) context.getAttribute("default_user");
```

But recently I've read that it's not recommended to use context attributes when you deploy your webapp in several servers.

Is that true?
How could I solve that? Maybe I would use several servers in the future (AWS or other stuff).

Thanks!

PS: I really only use that context attributes for read-only purposes, just read config parameters.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: I've read a lot of documentation. I can't remember where (in the tons of papers I read) I found it. It could be a falsehood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. see [Servlet Context in Clustered Environment](https://coderanch.com/t/612981/java/Servlet-Context-Clustered-Environment), which explains the problem:

> In cases where the container is distributed over many virtual machines, a Web application will have an instance of the ServletContext for each JVM.
>
> Context attributes are local to the JVM in which they were created. This prevents ServletContext attributes from being a shared memory store in a distributed container. When information needs to be shared between servlets running in a distributed environment, the information should be placed into a session , stored in a database, or set in an Enterprise JavaBeans component. Session attributes must be serializable if they are to be processed across multiple JVMs, which is a requirement for clustering. It is possible to make some fields of a session attribute non-clustered by declaring those fields as transient.

Comment: So, my "default_user" ServletContext attribute would work. I guess it would be copied among each server, isn't it?

Comment: @Ommadawn No, context attributes are *not* copied. *"Context attributes are **local to the JVM** in which they were created. This **prevents ServletContext attributes from being a shared** memory store in a distributed container."*

Comment: So, simply: if I only store in context read-only attributes, could it be any problem? I can't understand it very well...

Comment: @Ommadawn The problem is that context attributes are not distributed / copied between servers. If you don't need that, then *you* don't have a problem. It is generally *recommended* to not use context attributes *because* they are not distributed, because most uses are for storing shared updatable values.

Comment: Ok Andreas. I just want to use them to store read-only values, so I guess I should won't have problems (I hope). Thanks.